# Is it possible to direct output from build scripts the Xcode build log?

Tags: xcode4, build-process, logging, xcodebuild

Is there a way to direct output from Xcode build scripts to the build log window in Xcode?

I've see it [claimed](http://briksoftware.com/blog/?p=120) that that 'echo' will do this, but my results do not appear in Xcode, but in system.log instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pipe your output with "open -f" ?
Just like this:

```
 myscrpit.sh   2>&1 | open -f
```

It will bring up textedit with your log.